# How can I scale an OSMF player in ActionScript 3/Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, video, osmf

I am trying to create a simple video player SWF using the open source media framework in Flex 4. I want to make it dynamically scale based on the dimensions of the video, input by the user. I am following the directions on [the Adobe help site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/OSMF/1.0/Dev/WSc6f922f643dd2e6d-6937a7d01265bf23dd8-7ff4.html), but the video does not seem to scale properly. Depending on the size, sometimes videos play larger than the space allotted on the webpage, and sometimes smaller. The only way I have been able to get it to work properly is by including a SWF metadata tag hardcoding the width and height, but I can't use that if I want to make the player dynamically sized. My code is :

```
package { 
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

import org.osmf.media.MediaElement;
import org.osmf.media.MediaPlayer;
import org.osmf.media.URLResource;
import org.osmf.containers.MediaContainer;
import org.osmf.elements.VideoElement;
import org.osmf.layout.LayoutMetadata;

public class GalleryVideoPlayer extends Sprite { 
    private var videoElement:VideoElement; 
    private var mediaPlayer:MediaPlayer;
    private var mediaContainer:MediaContainer;

    private var flashVars:Object;

    public function GalleryVideoPlayer() {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        flashVars = loaderInfo.parameters;

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        videoElement = new VideoElement(new URLResource(flashVars.file));

        mediaContainer = new MediaContainer();

        var layoutMetadata:LayoutMetadata = new LayoutMetadata();
        layoutMetadata.width = Number(flashVars.width);
        layoutMetadata.height = Number(flashVars.height);

        videoElement.addMetadata(LayoutMetadata.LAYOUT_NAMESPACE, layoutMetadata);

        mediaPlayer.media = videoElement;
        mediaContainer.addMediaElement(videoElement); 

        addChild(mediaContainer);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about flex but i've used an OSMF player called the StrobeMediaPlayback and embedded it onto a html page. There's a javascript bridge which you can call using the ExternalInterface.call() function in actionscript (within the player code).

So I wrote a javascript function to resize the swf (can be done easily using jquery) and called it from actionScript whenever the video had to scale.

See if this helps you.